# Dynamic TextBlock font size in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamic, font-size

I am currently wrapping my TextBlock in a Viewbox as suggested by a couple of answers here on StackOverflow, and this renders as I want it to. But after doing a little research, I understand that this hampers performance, especially when you have a decent number of TextBlocks which use this approach.

Is there a better way of doing this in Silverlight?

**Note:** I don't mind using something other than a TextBlock as long as I can display text.

Comment: What's controlling the size of the text? You can bind the `FontSize` to another element in your view or a property in your view model.

Comment: Not sure if that's possible because I use dynamic proportional sizing for almost all my controls (using Grids). Since I use TextBlocks all over the place, I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't require explicitly calculating and binding the font size.

Comment: You have something like this: `FontSize="{Binding ElementName=YourGrid, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}"` The converter will take the `ActualHeight` of the Grid (say) and do what ever you want with it - use relative calcuations. More info - http://www.chrisforman.me.uk/2011/05/a-nifty-silverlight-feature/. Not sure it's what you want though, hence it's not an answer (yet).

Comment: Even though ActualWidth/ActualHeight are dependency properties, binding to them in Silverlight is not a smart idea as they're calculated properties (so a property changed notification does NOT fire when they change).

Comment: Ah - the case where I have it working is one where the `ActualWidth` doesn't change. I only used it here as an example, is there another property you can use?

Comment: Not one that I can think of, unfortunately. I was really hoping for some built-in Silverlight construct that I was unaware of :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From this forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/174546.aspx/1)

```
// Event handler
private void ControlsSizeChanged(object sender, System.Windows.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    GetFontSize(sender as Control);
}

// Method for font size changes
public static void GetFontSize(Control control)
{
    PropertyInfo info;
    if (control == null || control.ActualHeight <= 0)
        return;
    if(( info = control.GetType().GetProperty("FontSize", typeof(double))) != null)
    {
        info.SetValue(control, 0.7 * control.ActualHeight, null);
    }
}
```

No ViewBoxes involved just a magic calculation. There are other suggestions in the thread such as changing the font size and measuring a couple of times until the text fits.

Comment: I was hoping to find a XAML only solution, but this is better than using ViewBoxes all over the place. Thanks :)